# Definition of $f'(1)$ and use it to calculate $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+2x^2}$

Tags: derivatives

I need to use the definition of $f'(1)$ to calculate $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+2x^2}$

I can give the definition of Differentiate as limit:

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0+h) - f(x_0)}{h}$$

but I'm not sure that this is the right answer for $f'(1)$, is it?

If it is the correct answer how should I prcede? maybe in this way?

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\bigg(\frac{1}{1+2(1+h)^2}\bigg) - \frac{1}{1+2(1)^2}}{h}$$

Edit:
here how I proceded

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\bigg(\frac{1}{1+2(1+h^2+2h)}\bigg) - \frac{1}{3}}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\bigg(\frac{1}{1+2+2h^2+4h}\bigg) - \frac{1}{3}}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\bigg(\frac{3-(3+2h^2+4h)}{3(3+2h^2+4h)}\bigg)}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{3-3-2h^2-4h}{3h(3+2h^2+4h)}$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h(-2h-4)}{3h(3+2h^2+4h)}$$
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-2h-4}{3(3+2h^2+4h)} = -\frac{4}{9}$$

is this correct?

Comment: Correct(If you are trying to evaluate $f'(1)$). Now simplify that large expression.

Comment: "To solve..." **what**?

Comment: Reduce to same denominator, expand and simplify.

Comment: What does mean ‘to solve an *expression*’? Usually, we solve problems, equations, &c.

Comment: I have edited the question, @DonAntonio & Bernard you're right, I have replaced "solve"  with "calculate"

Comment: Yes, the computation is correct. What you meant (and did not say correctly) was that $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+2x^2}$ and that you wanted to compute $f'(1)$ ;)

Comment: Thanks, I have edited with $f(x)$

Comment: Oh, now it is clear...and then yes: the result is correct.